# Vote limit on comments?

Tags: support, bug

I was reviewing [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847468/updated-ubuntu-16-04-lts-and-now-i-cant-log-in) in the Close votes queue and upvoted the comment that mentioned the correct duplicate. I received a message regarding hitting the vote limit. I proceeded to VTC the as the flagged duplicate and the system happily accepted that.but I was somewhat baffled by the message. I am unaware of a limit on comment voting. Is this a rare bug that I've stumbled across or is there indeed a limit on comment voting? If the latter, what purpose does it serve?